# SecurityError IE canvas.toDataURL('image/png') same server

Tags: javascript, canvas, svg, cors, data-uri

I think this is a common known problem by some of you about CORS, only in IE (10 or 11).

Happens that I want to convert an image from svg to png and then send it to the server to be processed.

I'm using the saveSvgAsPng.js library, and I edited it to get the dataUri of my svg image as png:

```
      out$.svgAsPngDataUri = function(uri, cb) {
      //out$.svgAsDataUri(el, scaleFactor, function(uri) {
      var image = new Image();
      image.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
      image.src = 'http://localhost/terepss/tmp/'+uri;//Uri is the name of the svg image
      image.onload = function() {
        var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
        canvas.width = image.width;
        canvas.height = image.height;
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
        context.drawImage(image, 0, 0);

         if(cb) {
          cb(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'));//Here is the problem
         } 
      }
    //});
  };
```

As you can see, the image.src is localhost, same as my script, and even if I change it to 127.0.0.1 or my network's ip 192.168.0.12, it's throwing the same error.

What's wrong?

Thank you in advance.